# Will Google Search Console settings be the same when accessing the same site through a new account?

Tags: google-search-console

I have a website and I've verified it on Google Webmaster Tools and configured it, but I forgot the password and I think there isn't a way to recover it.

If I verified a new owner for my site in Google Webmaster Tools, should I re-configure it again, or will it recover the old configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I verified a new owner for my site in Google Webmaster Tools, should I re-configure it again, or will it recover the old configurations?

It will "recover the old configuration". You're not removing the first owner, you are simply verifying another, which accesses the same "data".

Comment: Thanks a lot, you mean that I must verify the new owner without removing the old verification file form my public_html, or it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, I certainly wouldn't remove the old verification at least initially. But I don't think it would really matter.

Answer (score 2):

w3dk is right, I added my same website on other gmail account, and I got same old analytics data in other accounts. It means if we verified same website with different tokens(Meta tags and Txt records) then both will be owner of that property.

Thank you w3dk to correct me.

[image]

Comment: I assume that this was downvoted because it doesn't address the question of whether or not settings are retained when search console is accessed from a new account.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but I don't get an answer for my question

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, I can at least do something. I appreciate your pitching in. Sometimes we strike-out. Sometime we hit a home run. Sometimes we just get a base hit. At least you got up to bat for the team. To me, that is what is most important! Cheers!!

Comment: "and from that old gmail account, your site will be remove automatically." - no it won't. The site will remain verified by the old Google account. There will be two verified owners. That is unless you explicitly remove the HTML file or tag associated with the old account (if that was the method of verification used). In which case, the old account will _eventually_ become unverified. "No need to add another owner" - Verifying another account does exactly this, it adds another verified _owner_.

Comment: @w3dk, you're right :) Let me edit my answer.